# Вычисление факториала рекурсивно

Tags: python, алгоритм, рекурсия

Как вычислить факториал рекурсивно? Циклом это сделать просто:

```
n = int(input())

factorial = 1

for i in range(2, n+1):
    factorial *= i

print(factorial)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как написать рекурсивную функцию для факториала числа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1314256/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: Скорее там дубликат вопроса. Он позже был задан.

Comment: я руководствовался комментарием @MSDN.WhiteKnight : "Отмечается дубликатом того, где лучше ответы, независимо от даты.". Отсюда: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6954

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0: return 1
    return n*factorial(n-1)

n = int(input())

print(factorial(n))
```