# Как написать рекурсивную функцию для факториала числа?

Tags: python

Я смог найти факториал числа с помощью циклов, а с помощью рекурсии не получается придумать решение.
Вот мой код:

```
a = int(input())
if a == 0:
    print(1)
else:
    for i in range(1,a):
        a = a*i
    print(a)
```

Желательно с объяснением.

Comment: в этом коде нет рекурсии

Comment: Я и написал, что не могу написать рекурсию, только это.

Comment: А как же написать, если не пытаться? В вопрос нужно прикладывать свои попытки решить задачу, а не просто какой-то любой код.

Comment: Чтобы можно было сделать рекурсию, как минимум нужно добавить функцию. А дальше внутри этой функции делать вызов самой себя.

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1111847/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Факториал - произведение всех натуральных чисел от 1 до n включительно, поэтому можно записать факториал так:

> Факториал какого-то числа равен этому числу, умноженному на
> уменьшенный на единицу факториал этого же числа, то есть `n! = n * (n - 1)!`

```
def factorial(n):
    if (n == 0 or n == 1): # Факториал 1 и 0 равны 1
        return 1 # Поэтому возвращаем 1
    else: 
        return n * factorial(n-1) # Возвращаем произведение числа на факториал числа на единицу меньше
```